# How to match required characters in random order using regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I need to match text which has `@`, `#`, and any number in it. The characters can be in random position as long as they are in the text. Given this input:

```
abc@#d9
a9b#c@d
@@abc#9
abc9d@@
a#b#c@d
```

The regex should match the first 3 lines. Currently my regex is:

```
/@.*?#.*?[0-9]/
```

Which doesn't work since it will only match the three chars in sequence. How to match the three chars in random order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found one of this ugly regex, if you really must use one:

`/(?=.*@)(?=.*#)(?=.*[0-9]).*/`

http://jsfiddle.net/BP53f/2/

The regex is basically using what they call `lookahead`

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

A simple case from the link above is trying to match `q`, followed by `u`, by doing `q(?=u)`, that's why it's called `lookahead`, it finds `q` followed by `u` ahead.

Let's take one of your valid case: `a9b#c@d`

The first lookahead is `(?=.*@)`, which states: Match anything, followed by a `@`. So it does, which is the string `a9b#c`, then since the match from the lookahead must be discarded, the engine steps back to the start of the string, which is an `a`. Then it goes to

`(?=.*#)`, which states: Match anything that is followed by `#`, then it finds it at `a9b`. etc. The difference between using lookahead and `(a)(b)(c)` is basically the stepping back.

From the link above:

> Let's take one more look inside, to make sure you understand the
>   implications of the lookahead. Let's apply q(?=u)i to quit. I have
>   made the lookahead positive, and put a token after it. Again, q
>   matches q and u matches u. **Again, the match from the lookahead must be
>   discarded**, so the engine steps back from i in the string to u. The
>   lookahead was successful, so the engine continues with i. But i cannot
>   match u. So this match attempt fails. All remaining attempts will fail
>   as well, because there are no more q's in the string.

It is ugly because it's difficult to maintain... You basically have 3 different sub-regex inside the brackets.

Comment: Add some explanation for this regex will be better.

Comment: And I need the explanation about the "ugly" part from "this ugly regex"

Answer (score 0):

Use separate expressions to make sure @ and # are present. Once they are, remove them and match for the rest of the characters/digits.

Comment: Too much effort for to easy a task.

Comment: Is that so? What's your solution than?

Comment: +1 because this is clearer, easier to write, and easier to maintain. Alternately, plain string operations would do the trick too.

Comment: You could easily use string functions if not [0-9] which becomes somewhat bothersome to use that way, but even if using string functions, there is no need to replace anything with anything - searches are good enough. For example: `echo (strspn("#@","@@abc#9")==2 && strpbrk("@@abc#9","0123456789"));`

Answer (score 0):

Decided I better write this as an answer:

```
$text = "a9b#c@d";
$themAll = "#@";
$themAny = "0123456789";
echo (strspn($themAll, $text)==strlen($themAll) && strpbrk($text, $themAny));
```

For maintenance and some (limited) extending this should be as easy as it gets, especially whth longer `$themAll` lists.